M-Q, command Q not mappable on a mac
I am using doom-emacs on a Mac (Mac silicon).
I am trying to map some function to M-Q key on a mac, but somehow it executes some weird commands.
I can't even search the command to which it is bound via helpful-key.
Does someone has an idea how I can bind Cmd-Q key (capital q)?

Cmd-Q may be intercepted by the OS, in which case Emacs cannot see it at all.

Maybe, I know Cmd-q is intercepted, but Cmd-Q not sure. Some command get's executed, but I don't understand what happens exactly.

If you say C-h k Cmd-Q in Emacs, does it say anything about what the key is bound to? Or is it waiting as if you typed nothing (regardless of what happened outside Emacs)? If the former, what is the key bound to? If the latter, then you know that the OS intercepted the key.

It doesn't say anything about what the key is bound to. I guess I've posted in the wrong forum, since it seems OS intercepts the key and it's not emacs error. Should I close the question somehow?

You can close the question as a (near-) duplicate. There are many more such questions on this site, but I cannot find what I (somewhat vaguely) remember to be the definitive explanation.

I don't have enough reputation to close my own question, should I delete it?
